# create 'bare' git repo without cloning it

Tags: git

[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book) states that I need to create repo inside existing directory first and then clone it as 'bare'. I've read [this article](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html) about why use 'bare' repository and it seems that I need to treat it as 'origin' and it should be used to pull from and push to. What I don't understand is that why I need to create regural repository first and then clone it as 'bare'? Why can't I create 'bare' repo intiatilly and then commit files from directory there?

And what if I remove the directory from which 'bare' repo was created? Will it affect somehow 'bare' repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a bare respository easily enough:

```
$ git init --bare <directory>
```

And if you cloned it, you can delete the original repository once cloned. The `origin` remote in the cloned repository will be unreachable, so you will probably want to remove it afterwards.

Not that remotes are very useful in bare repositories anyway...

Comment: Thanks! I've figured out that the repository you clone from becomes 'origin' in git remote list :)

Comment: `And if you cloned it, you can delete the original repository once cloned.` - I guess this could be a good addition to first option listed in the post by @Nevik Rehnel

Comment: You can, but you don't have to, @Maximus. You could just use the initial repo as a normal working clone.

Comment: Some bare repos have useful remotes, when they are being used as read-only caches.  For instance, $LargeCompany might have the "real" repo at $HQ but have read-only copies at $SiteB, $SiteC, etc., with the copies updated frequently (perhaps even automatically on pushes to $HQ) and individual engineers at $SiteB cloning from the $SiteB copy, to avoid a lot of traffic having to flow over the pipe to $HQ.

Comment: Thanks guys for your eleboration!

Answer (score 2):

This might be a slight misunderstanding of the starting situation.

You *can* create a bare repo like any other, by using `git init --bare`. This will create the repository without any contents.

However, without having a clone to communicate with, **you have no way of getting files into it**, because *bare repos have no working directory*.

If you want to put your existing files into a bare repo, you have two ways of going about that:

1. Create a normal repo and commit your files to it, then clone it into a bare repo (as described in your question)
2. Create a bare repo, clone it to a normal repo, commit your files to the normal repo, then push to the bare repo.

Leaving out the adding of a remote to the original non-bare in variant 1., you can see that variant 2. has more steps.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I guess this is a misunderstanding :). I guess I'm still lost as to why I need bare repo. Is there any good article on the web or question on stackoverflow that explains it?

Comment: Thanks! I guess now I've figured it out. I don't need to start with normal repo if I'm going to use 'bare' repo only for push/pull operations and actual commits will be made on local non-bare repositories.

Comment: Or 3. Create a bare repo, go to a normal repo, add the bare as remote, and push from there. This is what happens when you make a new repo on github and follow their instructions to push an existing repo.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't I create 'bare' repo intiatilly and then commit files from
>   directory there?

Because you *cannot commit files into a bare repo*.

Normally, if you create a repository (using `git init` or `git clone`), git will create the repository structure (the .git subdir) and a working tree, that is a directory where the current commit's files are checked out.

A bare repo is simply a repo without an associated working tree. So there's no way to commit files into it, because there is no working tree to put files into for committing.